# When defining keys in table, why is it inserted in a random order?

Tags: random, lua, key, lua-table

While working on a Love2d project, I noticed that when defining tables with a key and putting said tables in another table, in a loop, the tables were being inserted in a random order.

To test this, I made a short script that will hopefully explain my predicament a little better. My first assumption is because the keys are inserted wherever I have memory available, though I'm not sure. I've never encountered this before, anyone have any ideas?

[image]

Comment: `pairs` uses order of hashes of table keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lua implements tables as hash tables, hence the apparent random order when traversing them. That is by design so that access to tables can be done in amortized constant time.

If order is important to you, use sequential indices and complex values, like this

```
t[1] = { key="CA", value="California" }
t[2] = { key="TX", value="Texas" }
```

Comment: That makes sense to me. Thank you very much for clearing this up.

Comment: Good answer; I'd add that you can also use the integer keys to store a list of string keys which then point to your real values: `{'first', 'second', 'third', first='foo', second='bar', third="I'm last ;)"}` (Thus using only one table in total, which saves allocations and is easier on the GC) You can even go overkill and save the keys in the metatable; that only uses one more table, but is technically "cleaner"